# Embedding unmanaged dll into a managed C# dll

Tags: c#, unmanaged, dllimport, managed

I have a managed C# dll that uses an unmanaged C++ dll using DLLImport. All is working great.
However, I want to embed that unmanaged DLL inside my managed DLL as explain by Microsoft there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.dllimportattribute.aspx

So I added the unmanaged dll file to my managed dll project, set the property to 'Embedded Resource' and modify the DLLImport to something like:

```
[DllImport("Unmanaged Driver.dll, Wrapper Engine, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
```

where 
'Wrapper Engine' is the assembly name of my managed DLL
'Unmanaged Driver.dll' is the unmanaged DLL

When I run, I get:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I saw from MSDN and from http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/ that's supposed to be possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a C++ windows dll be merged into a C# application exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264/how-can-a-c-windows-dll-be-merged-into-a-c-sharp-application-exe)

Comment: You can consider BxILMerge for your case

Answer (score 67):

You can embed the unmanaged DLL as a resource if you extract it yourself to a temporary directory during initialization, and load it explicitly with LoadLibrary before using P/Invoke. I have used this technique and it works well. You may prefer to just link it to the assembly as a separate file as Michael noted, but having it all in one file has its advantages. Here's the approach I used:

```
// Get a temporary directory in which we can store the unmanaged DLL, with
// this assembly's version number in the path in order to avoid version
// conflicts in case two applications are running at once with different versions
string dirName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyAssembly." +
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
if (!Directory.Exists(dirName))
  Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
string dllPath = Path.Combine(dirName, "MyAssembly.Unmanaged.dll");

// Get the embedded resource stream that holds the Internal DLL in this assembly.
// The name looks funny because it must be the default namespace of this project
// (MyAssembly.) plus the name of the Properties subdirectory where the
// embedded resource resides (Properties.) plus the name of the file.
using (Stream stm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
  "MyAssembly.Properties.MyAssembly.Unmanaged.dll"))
{
  // Copy the assembly to the temporary file
  try
  {
    using (Stream outFile = File.Create(dllPath))
    {
      const int sz = 4096;
      byte[] buf = new byte[sz];
      while (true)
      {
        int nRead = stm.Read(buf, 0, sz);
        if (nRead < 1)
          break;
        outFile.Write(buf, 0, nRead);
      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    // This may happen if another process has already created and loaded the file.
    // Since the directory includes the version number of this assembly we can
    // assume that it's the same bits, so we just ignore the excecption here and
    // load the DLL.
  }
}

// We must explicitly load the DLL here because the temporary directory 
// is not in the PATH.
// Once it is loaded, the DllImport directives that use the DLL will use
// the one that is already loaded into the process.
IntPtr h = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
Debug.Assert(h != IntPtr.Zero, "Unable to load library " + dllPath);
```

Comment: Is LoadLibrary using DLLImport from kenel32?  Debug.Assert is failing for me using same code within WCF service.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it would be even better to find reliable resolution for cases when two applications attempt to write to the same location at the same time. The exception handler completes before the other application finishes unpacking the DLL.

Comment: This is perfect. Only unnecessary thing is that directory.createdirectory already has the directory exists check inside of it

Comment: I hate this method, it looks like a weird hack (I mean come on, saving temporary file, reading it in a different way and forgetting about it) but I couldn't find anything better.
And catching all exceptions is just meh, if we want to ignore the case when such file exists I think catching "IOException" would be enough. Despite all this, this is a nice simple example, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Here is my solution, which is a modified version of JayMcClellan's answer. Save the file below into a class.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Qromodyn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class used by managed classes to managed unmanaged DLLs.
    /// This will extract and load DLLs from embedded binary resources.
    /// 
    /// This can be used with pinvoke, as well as manually loading DLLs your own way. If you use pinvoke, you don't need to load the DLLs, just
    /// extract them. When the DLLs are extracted, the %PATH% environment variable is updated to point to the temporary folder.
    ///
    /// To Use
    /// <list type="">
    /// <item>Add all of the DLLs as binary file resources to the project Propeties. Double click Properties/Resources.resx,
    /// Add Resource, Add Existing File. The resource name will be similar but not exactly the same as the DLL file name.</item>
    /// <item>In a static constructor of your application, call EmbeddedDllClass.ExtractEmbeddedDlls() for each DLL that is needed</item>
    /// <example>
    ///               EmbeddedDllClass.ExtractEmbeddedDlls("libFrontPanel-pinv.dll", Properties.Resources.libFrontPanel_pinv);
    /// </example>
    /// <item>Optional: In a static constructor of your application, call EmbeddedDllClass.LoadDll() to load the DLLs you have extracted. This is not necessary for pinvoke</item>
    /// <example>
    ///               EmbeddedDllClass.LoadDll("myscrewball.dll");
    /// </example>
    /// <item>Continue using standard Pinvoke methods for the desired functions in the DLL</item>
    /// </list>
    /// </summary>
    public class EmbeddedDllClass
    {
        private static string tempFolder = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Extract DLLs from resources to temporary folder
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dllName">name of DLL file to create (including dll suffix)</param>
        /// <param name="resourceBytes">The resource name (fully qualified)</param>
        public static void ExtractEmbeddedDlls(string dllName, byte[] resourceBytes)
        {
            Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] names = assem.GetManifestResourceNames();
            AssemblyName an = assem.GetName();

            // The temporary folder holds one or more of the temporary DLLs
            // It is made "unique" to avoid different versions of the DLL or architectures.
            tempFolder = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", an.Name, an.ProcessorArchitecture, an.Version);

            string dirName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), tempFolder);
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
            }

            // Add the temporary dirName to the PATH environment variable (at the head!)
            string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            string[] pathPieces = path.Split(';');
            bool found = false;
            foreach (string pathPiece in pathPieces)
            {
                if (pathPiece == dirName)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", dirName + ";" + path);
            }

            // See if the file exists, avoid rewriting it if not necessary
            string dllPath = Path.Combine(dirName, dllName);
            bool rewrite = true;
            if (File.Exists(dllPath)) {
                byte[] existing = File.ReadAllBytes(dllPath);
                if (resourceBytes.SequenceEqual(existing))
                {
                    rewrite = false;
                }
            }
            if (rewrite)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(dllPath, resourceBytes);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        /// <summary>
        /// managed wrapper around LoadLibrary
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dllName"></param>
        static public void LoadDll(string dllName)
        {
            if (tempFolder == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("Please call ExtractEmbeddedDlls before LoadDll");
            }
            IntPtr h = LoadLibrary(dllName);
            if (h == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Exception e = new Win32Exception();
                throw new DllNotFoundException("Unable to load library: " + dllName + " from " + tempFolder, e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Mark, this is really cool.  For my uses, I found I could remove the LoadDll() method, and call LoadLibrary() at the end of ExtractEmbeddedDlls(). This also allowed me to remove the PATH modifying code.

Answer (score 10):

I wasn't aware this is possible - I'd guess that the CLR needs to extract the embedded native DLL somewhere (Windows needs to have a file for the DLL to load it - it cannot load an image from raw memory), and wherever it's trying to do that the process does not have permission.

Something like [Process Monitor from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) might give you a clue if the pronblem is that creating the DLL file is failing...

Update:

---

Ah... now that I've been able to read Suzanne Cook's article (the page didn't come up for me before), note that she is not talking about embedding the native DLL as a resource inside the managed DLL, but rather as a *linked resource* - the native DLL still needs to be its own file in the file system.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawyf94k.aspx, where it says:

> The resource file is not added to the output file. This differs from the /resource option which does embed a resource file in the output file.

What this seems to do is add metadata to the assembly that causes the native DLL to logically be part of the assembly (even though it's physically a separate file).  So things like putting the managed assembly into the GAC will automatically include the native DLL, etc.

Comment: How to use "linkresource" options in Visual Studio? I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 10):

You can try [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura). Documentation says, that it's able to handle unmanaged files. I only used it for managed files, and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

One could also just copy the DLLs to any folder, and then call [SetDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx) to that folder. No call to LoadLibrary is needed then.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
```

Comment: Great idea, just note that this might have security ramifications, as it opens up for dll injection, so in a high security environment it should be used with caution