# 'Faking' a project reference?

Tags: .net, msbuild, build-events

I have a solution structure like in [Ports And Adapters Architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) or [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). My composition root (a web application in this case) and infrastructure libraries only reference the core library.

I can also load infrastructure libraries at runtime using Castle Windsor. However I do not reference these libraries on my composition root so their build output is not copied to the output folder. I guess I need a custom build step but I don't know how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Look at this, I think it will get you what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776060/how-to-make-visual-studio-copy-dll-to-output-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with setting unreferenced projects' output path same same as the web application's.

```
..\WebApp\bin
```

This works well for building the solution inside Visual Studio. For release builds (only building the Website project) I wrote a custom script that builds Web application and other libraries. After those libraries are built, all dll files are copied to `WebApp\bin` folder inside `_PublishedWebsites` using a [Copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a post build event to copy the assemblies to the output directory. Here is a tutorial you'll be able to get a good feel for it from.

http://eyeung003.blogspot.com/2009/11/visual-studio-post-build-event-to-copy.html?m=1