# Error 3 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gtk-3.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, gtk, gtk3

I have been trying to get GTK 3.0 to work, and have followed all the steps here

[How to configure gtk on Visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010)

And changing to 3.0 where needed to get GTK to work, and it seems to have loaded everything it needs in order to compile, but it gives me the error

```
Error   3   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gtk-3.lib'
```

Whenever I try to run the program.
I am using visual studios 2012, but this was the only place i found anything about getting GTK to run on any visual studios.
Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <gtk-3.0\gtk\gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    //gtk_widget_get_preferred_size(window, 300, 200);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);   
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK+ with VS2010");

    gtk_widget_show(window);     

    gtk_main();   
    return 0;
}
```

I commented out the gtk_widget_get_prefered_size call because it is irrelevant to the problem

any suggestions? I've looked in several places but none came up with clear answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library `gtk-3.lib` does not exist. In fact, the library reference is not required to build your GTK 3 application. The `pkg-config` helper doesn't seem to generate the correct linker flags needed to link your application.

Just add in your **Additional Options** area all the existing libraries found in your GTK package (\gtk3\lib). The lib files for my bundle (gtk+-bundle_3.6.4-20130921) were as follows:

> atk-1.0.lib cairo.lib fontconfig.lib gailutil.lib gdk-win32-3.0.lib gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib gio-2.0.lib glib-2.0.lib gmodule-2.0.lib gobject-2.0.lib gthread-2.0.lib gtk-win32-3.0.lib pango-1.0.lib pangocairo-1.0.lib pangoft2-1.0.lib pangowin32-1.0.lib

(or you can go to your library path via a command prompt and enter `dir *.lib /B`)

Don't forget to include the `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup` flag mention in the [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010) you started with.

Comment: You are right, pkg-config is producing references to non-existing libs. I can confirm that specifying the libs in the GTK lib folder, (the same ones as you have listed above) works as expected. Confirmed working with 3.6.4 on VS2010.

Comment: for other compiler errors, please see this answer, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883854/compiling-a-gtk3-program-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Do you know where to get the gtk3 bundle for windows?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to edit your project settings or use a pragma comment to link with your gtk library:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gtk-3")//if the libray is on your project's path


#define PATH "C:\\example\\"
#pragma comment(lib, PATH"gtk-3")//if the library is on PATH
```