# Compiling a GTK3 program in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, gtk, gtk3

With the release of Gtk 3 for windows I thought of upgrading my Gtk 2 C application to take advantage of the new GtkGrid widget.

The program compiles fine under linux or using MinGW (with codeblocks) under windows, however when I try the same set of files under Visual Studio 2012, giving me 50 or so compilation errors saying gutils.h, gtrashstack.h and gstring.h have a bunch of syntax errors (assuming I only use a basic program, with just a gtk_init and gtk_main).

Visual Studio handled gtk2 very well. Why is it refusing to compile with gtk3? Any way to get it to work with it?
As much as I love Code::Blocks, external powers force me to keep my code VS2012-compatible...

EDIT: I created a repository with a simple gtk3 program and preconfigured project files for VS2012 and Codeblocks. 
https://github.com/The-J-Person/Example-gtk3-vs2012-project

EDIT 2: Here's a list of the compilation errors given by VS2012:
http://pastebin.com/ThZpwVmg

Comment: I think you need to include correct "Include directory" in project settings..

Comment: I made sure of that. The errors are not regarding the compiler's inability to find a file - they claim there are syntax errors within gtk's header files, such as "expected { before const*".

Comment: I added a to a repo demonstrating this. If anyone could get what's in there to compile under VS2012, that'd be the solution.

Comment: Done. Edited to include link to error pastebin (I didn't add them to the post itself because it's rather long)

Comment: Did you solve your problem. I am upgrading a GTK2 code to GKT3 and I'm sure my code is correct, but VS2010 doesn't compile GTK headers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now an answer on the GTK mailing list.

> In gutils.h lines 82 and 122, and in gstring.h line 129, change
>   "static inline" to "static __inline". Alternatively add a
>   PreprocessorDefinition to the project file to define "inline" as
>   "__inline".

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2014-January/msg00011.html

That allowed my project to work just fine.