# Where can I read the output of g_print while debugging a GTK+ 3.0 project in VS2013?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, gtk3, debug-print

I have a GTK+3.0 project running in VS2013

I added to my linker command line options this argument:
`/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`

I suspect that might be related to the fact that I have no output in VS that shows the messages printed with `g_print`

I also tried calling `printf` and see no output in VS2013's output window, nor the "immediate window"

Does anyone have experience building C projects in VS2013 that use GTK+ 3.0 that could maybe tell me where I can see the messages printed by `g_print` and/or `printf`, or perhaps can you suggest a different way to debug print?

More details about how I set up the project in VS2013:

- [How to configure gtk on Visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010/17688546#comment42272778_17688546)
- [Error   3   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gtk-3.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128380/error3error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-gtk-3-lib/22117593#comment42273360_22117593)
- [Compiling a GTK3 program in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883854/compiling-a-gtk3-program-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 0):

To those who want to know..

I found the answer.

In my first link, the direction was to do the following:

> While we are still in the view of the Project Properties, click on
>   Linker and then System. Look for SubSystem on the right and click the
>   drop down box. Select Windows /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

If you omit this step, you get a GTK window and a console, where you can read the output of printf().