# GTK+ 3.0 in visual studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gtk, gtk3

I've tried to setup and configure GTK+ 3.0 in visual studio and run example project (with c code file) as explained  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010). However, when I compiled the code, I got lot of errors (around 50) and lot of warnings (around 80). I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289486/gtk-3-0-setup-in-visual-studio-2013), but it didn't work.

The errors I got is in the included headers files of GTK, like:

```
Error   17  error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'    c:\gtk\include\glib-2.0\glib\gutils.h

Error   27  error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'inline'  c:\gtk\include\glib-2.0\glib\gutils.h

Error   28  error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'gint'    c:\gtk\include\glib-2.0\glib\gutils.h
```

and warnings like:`Warning  24  warning C4431: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C no longer supports default-int c:\gtk\include\glib-2.0\glib\gutils.h`

This is the code I have used:

```
#include <gtk\gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_usize(window, 300, 200);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK+ with VS2010");

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone knows why does it happen?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Side notice: please use `/` as a directory separator in your include paths, it's more portable.

Comment: It's also unclear which GTK version you're using. I hope it's note 3.0 which was released 5½ years ago. Last stable is 3.22.16: http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.22/