# No display for GTK in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtk

After a couple of rounds of troubleshooting I was able to compile GTK source code in Visual Studio with no errors. I followed a procedure not too dissimilar to ['How to configure gtk on Visual studio 2010'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010). The code is as follows,

```
#include <gtk-2.0\gtk\gtk.h>
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
gtk_widget_set_usize(window, 300, 200);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),     NULL);
gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK+ with VS2010");

gtk_widget_show(window);

gtk_main();
return 0;
}
```

However on starting the code no window appears. Visual Studio simply indicates the solution is running but no window appears. Any ideas?

Comment: You should call `gtk_init` **before** creating any windows.

Comment: Initialisation was the issue. It's up. thanks.

Comment: @KAlistair : You have tagged c++. Hope you're aware of gtkmm, the C++ wrapper for gtk

Answer (score 2):

There's problem here:

```
GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
```

You should call [`gtk_init`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-init) *before* creating any windows:

> Call this function before using any other GTK+ functions in your GUI
>   applications. It will initialize everything needed to operate the
>   toolkit and parses some standard command line options.

Try:

```
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
GtkWidget* window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
```