# Makefile with C++ Gtkmm in Sublime Text

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, sublimetext3, gtkmm

As suggested to me [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976158/how-do-i-build-system-in-sublime-text-3-c-and-gtk), and apparently I needed Gtkmm and not Gtk+.

So I'm trying to build a simple project environment in Sublime Text 3, for coding in C++ and Gtkmm. 
The goal is to create a Makefile which will be use to compile the project.

I followed [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows) site instruction with setting up Gtkmm, and updating the `PATH`. (the main.cpp code, is from this site).

The project path: `D:\Test` and for now contains only `main.cpp`, `Makefile.make` and `Test.sublime-project`.

the Test.sublime-project code:

```
{
     "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "D:\\Test",
        }
   ],
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "all",
            "cmd":["make"],
            "file_regex" : "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:?(.*)$",
            "selector": "source.makefile, source.cpp",
        }
    ]
}
```

The Makefile code:

```
cc = g++ -wall
program_CPPFLAGS = $(GTKMM_CFLAGS)
program_LDADD = $(GTKMM_LIBS)
gtkmm = pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs | sed 's/ -I/ -isystem /g')
all:    
    $(cc)  $(program_CPPFLAGS) $(program_LDADD) main.cpp -o exec
```

the error I'm getting:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['make']]
[dir: D:\Test]
[path: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;...]
```

Please help me with it, I'm Googling ,testing and trying all sorts of things for days, and nothing.

Thank You!

Comment: It's mad because it can't find `make` anywhere in the path; presumably the binutils package you got that gave you `g++` also installed `make` for you; make sure those binaries can also be found on the path and you should be good.