# C & GTK with microsoft visual studio IDE, is that possible?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gtk

I started working in *GTK* with *C* and I'm very familiar with Microsoft Visual Studio.
I use for compiling *codeblocks* or *devC++* and even manual *gcc* command. But I wonder if the is a possibility to integrate *GTK* to the *VS IDE* because I know it's possible for *C*. I tried a lot but unfortunately with no success.

Thanks

PS: I have now VS 2017 RC but i can go back to VS Community 2015.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906580/how-to-configure-gtk-on-visual-studio-2010

Comment: It worked @CraigEstey thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for your build system. You should try a build system that generates project files for your IDE. For example, CMake, or even better, the meson build system, which is getting some attention on the GNOME and GTK community. Meson is easy to install: it only depends on python 3 and ninja (a faster replacement for `make`).

First,  create a file named `meson.build`

```
project('gtk test', 'c')
gtk_dep = dependency('gtk+-3.0')
executable('myapp', 'myapp.c',
  dependencies : gtk_dep)
```

Then put your application code in `myapp.c`

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        GtkWidget *window;

        gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello world !");
        g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

        gtk_widget_show_all (window);
        gtk_main ();

        return 0;
}
```

Finally, run meson in your Visual Studio environment to detect it. For that, follow the instructions at:
https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/wiki/Using-with-Visual-Studio

I never tried to use meson on Windows, but I'm pretty confident this should work. Feedback about the experience is welcome :)

Here are additional links to the meson documentation:

- http://mesonbuild.com/samples.html
- https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [wingtk](https://github.com/wingtk/gtk-win32) project to build the Gtk stack against msvc. From there you can just make a project file.