# How can I make Visual Studio copy the required .dll files into the release folder?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm using [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) with C++, developing a [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) application.

I'm able to compile it and debug it, but, somehow, no .dll file is in the *Debug* or *Release* folder. I've tried some of other posts solutions, but none worked.

So, how can I make Visual Studio copy the required .dll files into the release folder?

I think it should be an option somewhere. I'm just starting to think about copying it handmade.

Comment: You can try adding them as **resources**

Comment: In the **properties** of your project, there is a section named **resources**, I'm gonna add it as an answer

Comment: **Which** dll's are we talking about? What DLL do you need in the debug/release folders? Are these supposed to be built by your project, or are these the regular Qt  DLLs?

Comment: The regular Qt Dlls ones and the msvc ones too.

Comment: add a post-build event in project properties that copy dll's whenerer you want. Use environment variables in order to remain consistent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make visual studio copy dll to output directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776060/how-to-make-visual-studio-copy-dll-to-output-directory)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Too much bad advice, a DLL cannot be a resource.  Windows *demands* that code is stored in a separate executable file with a proper PE32 header.  Which permits it to create a memory-mapped file to map the file content into memory, allowing the code to be shared by multiple processes and keeping it out of the paging file.  And to relocate the code when the DLL's base address is already in use.

Simply use Project + Properties, Build events, Post-Build Event to xcopy the DLLs.  Arbitrarily, if you stored the needed DLLs in the "dlls" subdirectory of your project then this command will get them copied, only when necessary:

```
 xcopy /d /y "$(ProjectDir)dlls\*.*" "$(OutDir)"
```

Use it both in the Debug and Release configuration so you'll debug exactly what you'll ship.

Answer (score -2):

Add your `.dll` files as **resources** to your project. In this way your `.dll` files will be in a `resources` folder in you project.

Try `Add Item...` -> `New Item...` and add a resource (`.qrc`) file to the project and add the `.dll` files to that.

Comment: I've just get this warning when compiling: RCC : warning : No resources in 'C:\Users\Netwave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Shutdowner\Shutdowner\shutdowner.qrc'

Comment: Ok, I've been investigating, it should be between "Manifest Tool" and "XML Document Generator", but there is no such opction in mine... :S

Comment: @DanielSanchez: In your solution explorer, right click on your project name and at the end of the list you will see `Properties`

Comment: ow, try adding a new item, then add a resource file to the project