# Embed C++ Libraries into .Net Libraries

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

In my .Net assemblies I would have to make use of some native (C++ ) dlls. Usually we need to copy the C++ dlls into the bin folder and use `PInvoke` to call it. To save the distribution cost, I want to embed the C++ into my .Net dll direct, so that the number of assemblies distributed would be less.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding unmanaged dll into a managed C# dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666799/embedding-unmanaged-dll-into-a-managed-c-dll)

Comment: i disagree with closing as duplicate -- the answers for the other question describe the "embed as resources" part but not how to properly load the libraries once they have been extracted to the drive

Answer (score 4):

You would embed your native DLLs as resources.

Then at runtime, you would have to extract those native DLLs into a temporary folder; you don't necessarily have write access to the application folder when your application launches: think windows vista or windows 7 and UAC. As a consequence, you would use this kind of code to load them from a specific path:

```
public static class NativeMethods {

  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  private unsafe static extern void* LoadLibrary(string dllname);

  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  private unsafe static extern void FreeLibrary(void* handle);

  private sealed unsafe class LibraryUnloader
  {
    internal LibraryUnloader(void* handle)
    {
      this.handle = handle;
    }

    ~LibraryUnloader()
    {
      if (handle != null)
        FreeLibrary(handle);
    }

    private void* handle;

  } // LibraryUnloader


  private static readonly LibraryUnloader unloader;

  static NativeMethods()
  {
    string path;

    // set the path according to some logic
    path = "somewhere/in/a/temporary/directory/Foo.dll";    

    unsafe
    {
      void* handle = LoadLibrary(path);

      if (handle == null)
        throw new DllNotFoundException("unable to find the native Foo library: " + path);

      unloader = new LibraryUnloader(handle);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you extract them, why do you need to go the whole LoadLibrary route?

Comment: to load them from a specific path, not necessarily from the same path as the application executable

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your dlls as resources.

At runtime, extract them to the same folder as your exe and use P/Invoke to call methods inside them.

Comment: you don't necessarily have write access to the application folder when your application launches: think windows vista or windows 7 and UAC