# Wixsharp - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, wixsharp

I am trying to include some reference files in Wix# managed project using DefaultRefAssemblies.Add method:

```
ManagedProject project = new ManagedProject();
project.DefaultRefAssemblies.Add("FontAwesome.Sharp.dll");
project.DefaultRefAssemblies.Add("protobuf-net.dll");
project.DefaultRefAssemblies.Add("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
project.DefaultRefAssemblies.Add("ManagedOpenSsl.dll");
project.DefaultRefAssemblies.Add("ssleay32.dll");
```

When I try to build a MSI I get an error. The problem happens to be in loading of **ssleay32** assembly (part of OpenSSL). When I exclude this file, the build succeeds. Can you please help me understand the exception? The target framework of the Wix# project is .NET Framework 4.8.

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '361984 bytes loaded from WixSharp, Version=1.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3775edd25acc43c2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to mix x64 and x86 code

Comment: That was my first thought, so I tried to load both, x86 and x64 versions of ssleay32.dll. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Wixsharp supports .net assemblies compiled for:

1. Platform x86
2. Managed assemblies (Not native)
3. Target framework 3.5

So, make sure "ssleay32.dll" has 3 requirements above. Every ssleay32 assembly i have found was native (unmanaged).

*Workaround in case of no luck with*:

You can try to save ssleay32.dll to embedding resource file and before  "ManagedOpenSsl.dll" types usage you should load dll in the memory. [Load unmanaged assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666799/embedding-unmanaged-dll-into-a-managed-c-sharp-dll)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, ssleay32 is a native DLL. Thanks for the suggested solution. I will try it!