# embed a DLL into a console application

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Is it possible to embed a   DLL into a console application  If it is possible, how would one go about doing it?

Normally, I'm cool with just leaving the DLLs outside but there have been a couple of people at work who have asked me this and I honestly don't know.

Comment: Is it a .NET assembly or native code?

Comment: What do you mean by _embed_? You can reference, merge and import ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the libraries are also .NET, you can use ILMerge.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge

**Edit (after learning it is native code)**

Check out duplicate question here:
[How can a C++ windows dll be merged into a C# application exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264/how-can-a-c-windows-dll-be-merged-into-a-c-sharp-application-exe)

or

[Embedding unmanaged dll into a managed C# dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666799/embedding-unmanaged-dll-into-a-managed-c-sharp-dll/11038376#11038376)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) by Redgate as this can accomplish what you want. We use this tool to do exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ILMerge for .NET assemblies.  It won't work for native code.

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a
>   single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes
>   with several options for controlling the processing and format of the
>   output. See the accompanying documentation for details.

Download here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630