# ILMerge: How to merge Azure runtime library?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2012, ilmerge

I'm trying to use **ILMerge** to create a single executable that uses **Windows Azure SDK 2.0** including the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll`, which I added manually because I couldn't find any NuGET package that contains it.

I'm using the following command line on a VS2012 post-build event:

```
/wildcards /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /log:ILMerge.log /closed Output.exe *.dll /out:Executable.exe
```

However, I'm getting the following error in `ILMerge.log`, even though the output window reports no issues at all after building:

```
The assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime' was not merged in correctly. It is still listed as an external reference in the target assembly.
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: The assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime' was not merged in correctly. It is still listed as an external reference in the target assembly.
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

And then the executable throws the following exception when opened:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the 
target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file
or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
or one of its dependencies.
```

I have also tested the same output without merging and it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What will you do with this executable once you have it?

Comment: I'll include it in an installer package. I want to keep everything in a single file. Why?

Comment: I totally understand why you want a single executable for your installer. It is not a cloud service role, is it?

Comment: It's a WCF service. It's intended to run in two different scenarios: hosted by an Azure Web Role (no merging is done for this build) or by a Windows Service, in which case I want it merged.

I'm suspecting the problem is that `msshrtmi.dll` contains unmanaged code, and thus cannot be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem like this cannot be done, or at least not how I want it done.

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll` [seems to have a dependency](http://www.diversify.se/blogg/?m=20111108) on the native library  `msshrtmi.dll`. This means that ILMerge cannot handle it, since unmanaged code cannot be merged with managed code.

According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264/how-can-a-c-windows-dll-be-merged-into-a-c-sharp-application-exe) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666799/embedding-unmanaged-dll-into-a-managed-c-sharp-dll) questions there is a way to work around this problem, but it involves packaging the `msshrtmi.dll`as a resource and unpacking it when it's needed. I feel it's kinda hacky.

So I guess I'll just have to do what I should have done before: remove all references to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll` from the project that builds the merged, non-Azure version of my WCF service. This might involve using some IoC container and doing some heavy refactoring, which is why I was trying to avoid it at this stage.