# C# - Getting file version of embedded resource files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have several files that I have as embedded resources of a WPF application.  I would like to be able to find the file versions of these resources without writing them out to a file first.  Is this possible?

Comment: The answer to this question would seem to partially depend on the type of these files. Are these assemblies? Images? If they are not assemblies, how are they currently versioned?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this will help, but after searching for how to package my embedded resource .DLLs into one .exe, I ran into the code from below.  You can use `Assembly` to gather an embedded resources, such as a .DLL's File Version.  In short, using Assembly.Load(byte[]), you can figure out the file version.

```
var assemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resources = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(n => n.EndsWith(".dll"));

foreach (string resource in resources)
{
    using (var stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
    {
        if (stream == null)
            continue;

        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        try
        {
            //After Assembly.Load is called, you can find the File Version
            assemblies.Add(resource, Assembly.Load(bytes));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(string.Format("Failed to load: {0}, Exception: {1}", resource, ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Some source can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264/how-can-a-c-windows-dll-be-merged-into-a-c-sharp-application-exe).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file) might help too.

Comment: You should have added exact example , rather than pointing for potential solution

Comment: @RanDavidovitz I'm not here to do the busy work for OP, I'm here to give direction.  If OP can't figure out how to iterate through a dictionary and extract the data they need, they have bigger problems they should be worrying about.  I stated what would work for me, and that if it doesn't work for OP to look at the sources I used to see if they shed any light. Thanks for clarifying the down vote. I'm too lazy to show you how looping through collections is done.